# How to achieve test coverage of ref.current usage?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm getting the hang of `@testing-library/react` and testing in general, but I'm confused on how to achieve 100% coverage via `jest` on the usage of `useRef` where we want to run a side effect or even a function body that is triggered on the condition that `ref.current` exists. In my context, I only care if the component is rendered and that's when I perform my dom mutations on the dom elements. I know it's not ideal, but it's the use case that I'm facing by using another library.

Here's a simple component demonstrating my issue:

```
export const Test: React.FC<TestProps> = ({text}) => {
  const ref = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current !== null) { // this is line 11 which is not covered according to jest below
      const span = ref.current.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];

      span.setAttribute('data-test', 'attribute has been set');
    }
  }, [ref.current]);

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <span>{text}</span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And here's the test. I know that there are recommended queries provided by `screen` such as `getByRole`, but libraries that are poorly labeled/tagged force me to rely on the more traditional `enzyme` method of using classic document queries to target elements that I need to mutate and assert against.

```js
it('renders and sets attribute', () => {
  const {container} = render(<Test text="hello" />);

  expect(container.getElementsByTagName('span')[0]).toHaveAttribute(
    'data-test',
    'attribute has been set'
  );
});
```

The test actually passes, which means the side effect was run and asserted. When the test runs, `ref.current` is true and the side effect is applied via `useLayoutEffect`. I've heard that asserting the side effect should work and count as coverage, but that's not what I'm seeing. I've also heard that it's possible that I need to rerender the component to be able to confirm coverage of the logic, but using RTL's `rerender` didn't do anything either.

Getting the coverage via jest shows:

```
-------------------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                                 | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
-------------------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
 components/Test                     |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 |
  Test.tsx                           |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 11
```

Any help would be appreciated. I searched everywhere, but couldn't figure out how to address this use case where I want test coverage on the condition/branch that `ref.current` exists, where the `ref` is attached to a dom element. Perhaps this isn't the correct paradigm I'm thinking in?

Comment: I believe the missing 50% branches being reported is due to when `ref.current` is `null` and the code doesn't get inside the `if` statement. Coverage will expect both branches (when condition is `true` AND when it's `false`) to be tested. In this particular case could you not just remove the condition altogether? The code is running inside `useLayoutEffect` meaning `ref.current` will always be set.

Comment: @juliomalves you're right, I removed the if statement earlier because my understanding is that ```useLayoutEffect``` runs after rendering but before painting to the dom, which means that if there's a ref that just tracks the wrapper for the component's return value then it will always exist within ```useLayoutEffect```. My mistake was that I forgot to assert within typescript that ref.current is a div element. Changing my code to this solves everything. Thank you!  

`const span = (ref.current as HTMLDivElement).getElementsByTagName('span')[0];`